# Setting Up Analytics eCommerce with two GTM properties

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to pass the data layer for one of our third party booking engines. They set up a GTM property that already has the data layer set up. I also have our own site in a GTM property. How would I push the data to the website or do I have to set up cross domain tracking? Just a little confused reading all of the docs.

Thanks!

This is the trigger for the data layer, which is then loaded into User Defined Variables within the GTM module. I have already been able to push the data to Adwords by just referencing a page load event and passing along the variables.

```
<script>
if(window.multiRoomReservation != undefined){
    dataLayer.push(function(){
    var transactionProduct = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.get('ihReservations').length; i ++){
      var price = this.get('ihReservations')[i].ihAmount / this.get('ihReservations')[i].ihNights;
        transactionProduct.push({
        'sku': this.get('ihReservations')[i].ihConfirmID,
        'name': this.get('ihReservations')[i].ihRoomType,
        'category': this.get('ihReservations')[i].ihRatePlanName,
        'price': price,
        'quantity': this.get('ihReservations')[i].ihNights,
        })
    }

  dataLayer.push({
    'transactionId':'{{ihHotelName}}'+' '+'{{ihConfirmID}}',
    'transactionTotal': {{ihAmount}},
    'transactionTax': {{ihTaxes}},
    'transactionProducts': transactionProduct
    })
  });
}else{
dataLayer.push({
   'transactionId':'{{ihHotelName}}'+' '+'{{ihConfirmID}}',
   'transactionTotal': {{ihAmount}},
   'transactionTax': {{ihTaxes}},
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'sku': '{{ihConfirmID}}',
       'name': '{{ihRoomType}}',
       'category': '{{ihRatePlanName}}',
       'price': '{{ihAmount}}'/'{{ihNights}}',
       'quantity': {{ihNights}}
   }]
});

}

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have 2 GTM containers?  Elaborate a little more, please.

Comment: Yeah, I have two GTM containers. The third vendor site gave me a container that has a data layer already set up. I need to populate my Analytics Ecommerce data with this data layer.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the structure of your dataLayer?

Comment: Just added the code and some info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-domain tracking is meant for user identification between the sites.

Let's say when a user in your site clicked the third party site,he will be redirected to the site along with ga cookies meaning which both are same user in spite of counting it as 2 different users in the google analytics between the sites.

And this tracking is suitable for one or more sites pointing to same GA property.